# Tilable 3d noise in texture?

Tags: perlin-noise, texture-packing

I've looked high and low for an answer to this, but I haven't found anything yet. Here's my question:

Can you pack pre-calculated noise into a 2d texture in such a way as to be able to calculate a reasonable facsimile of 3d noise without the overhead of having to calculate it with a full blown 3d noise algorithm.

My initial idea was to take Z slices of X by Y noise and pack them up side by side, then for every pixel to calculate the 'low' and 'high' noise pixels and do a weighted interpolation between the two Z samples. Needless to say this didn't work very well.

I know about the various shaders that generate noise, but by and large they have problems on the mobile platform due to the low spec hardware and various optimizations that the mfrs have put into place, so it's not viable to calculate on the fly.